# How protect/license an Eclipse RCP feature/product?

Tags: eclipse, licensing, rcp

How can I protect an Eclipse RCP based product?

What I would like to do is ask for a licence key to the user and avoid adding more plugins or changing plugins that aren't 'signed by me'.

Is there some plug-in to do this? Or should I use an external lincense tool like License3j or truelicense?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest solution would be to properly configure your p2 update mechanism by changing the visibility of available content or just switching to headless updates and disable update manager menu all together, this should solve your 'install plugins' issue. For the licence key you can create a separate plugin where you will add functionlity to check the licence key on the server, locally - endless possibilities.

More info on configuring p2 can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application